# How can I sort an array on based number?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array whith the following content:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'https://www.facebook.com' (length=24)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)    // order number
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'https://www.twiiter.com' (length=23)
      2 => string '7' (length=1)   // order number
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'https://www.instagram.com' (length=25)
      2 => string '9' (length=1)   // order number
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'https://www.linkedin.com' (length=24)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)  // order number
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'https://www.pinterest.com' (length=25)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)  // order number
```

I want to sort this array based on the number in the above code. (where is a written comment).

How can I do this?

So far I have written the following code but I do not know how to make it properly.

```
$arrMerge = array_merge($facebookURL, $twitterURL, $instagramURL, $linkedinURL, $pinterestURL);
$splitArr = array_chunk($arrMerge, 3);
```

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_multisort` with `array_column`

```
array_multisort(array_column($arr, 2), SORT_ASC,$arr)
```

You can use `SORT_ASC` OR `SORT_DESC` as you required

[Live DEMO](https://3v4l.org/eFXXR)

Comment: array_multisort return boolean, how can I display the values from this array into var_dump() function?

Comment: @Cristi you can use the same array variable to`print_r` or `var_dump` i.e. `print_r($arr)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[2] - $b[2];
});
```

You might also want to type-cast the result to an integer before-hand as it looks like your data is treated as a string.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return (int)$a[2] - (int)$b[2];
});
```

This is also a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?noredirect=1&lq=1).